# Yii2 Setting unknown property: yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::formats

Tags: php, apache, rest, api, yii

I am creating apis in `YII2` each and every request is working well but in `PUT` request I am getting below error

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> Setting unknown property: yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::formats

This is my stack trace

> 1. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php at line 161 152153154155156157158159160161162163164165166167168169170
>      */
>      public function __set($name, $value)
>      {
>          $setter = 'set' . $name;
>          if (method_exists($this, $setter)) {
>              $this->$setter($value);
>          } elseif (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
>              throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
>          } else {
>              throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
>          }
>      }
>
>    /**
>
>    - Checks if a property is set, i.e. defined and not null.
>        *
>    - Do not call this method directly as it is a PHP magic method that
>    - will be implicitly called when executing `isset($object->property)`.
>        *
> 2. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 525 – yii\base\Object::__set('formats', ['application/json' =>
>      'json'])
> 3. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php at line 105 – yii\BaseYii::configure(yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth,
>      ['only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' =>
>      ['application/json' => 'json']])
> 4. yii\base\Object::__construct(['only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' => ['application/json' => 'json']])
> 5. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 381 – ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs([['only' => ['index',
>      'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' => ['application/json' =>
>      'json']]])
> 6. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 156 – yii\di\Container::build('yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth',
>      [], ['only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats'
>      => ['application/json' => 'json']])
> 7. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 344 – yii\di\Container::get('yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth', [],
>      ['only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' =>
>      ['application/json' => 'json']])
> 8. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 667 – yii\BaseYii::createObject(['class' =>
>      'yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth', 'only' => ['index', 'view',
>      'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' => ['application/json' =>
>      'json']])
> 9. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 651 – yii\base\Component::attachBehaviorInternal(0, ['class'
>      => 'yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth', 'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', ...], 'formats' => ['application/json' =>
>      'json']])
> 10. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 533 – yii\base\Component::ensureBehaviors()
> 11. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 272 – yii\base\Component::trigger('beforeAction',
>       yii\base\ActionEvent)
> 12. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php at line 164 – yii\base\Controller::beforeAction(yii\rest\UpdateAction)
> 13. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 154 – yii\web\Controller::beforeAction(yii\rest\UpdateAction)
> 14. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php at line 523 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('update', ['id' => '1'])
> 15. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php at line 102 – yii\base\Module::runAction('products/update', ['id' =>
>       '1'])
> 16. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php at
>       line 380 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
> 17. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connect\index.php at line 12 – yii\base\Application::run() 6789101112  require(**DIR** .
>       '/vendor/autoload.php'); require(**DIR** .
>       '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');   $config = require(**DIR** .
>       '/config/web.php');   (new yii\web\Application($config))->run(); 
>       $_GET = [
>       'id' => '1', ]; Yii Framework 2017-02-23, 09:31:51
>
> Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28 Yii Framework/2.0.11.2

Behaviors in controller is

```
  public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'search'],
                'formats' => ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['get'],
                    'view' => ['get'],
                    'create' => ['post'],
                    'update' => ['PUT'],
                    'delete' => ['delete'],
                    'deleteall' => ['post'],
                    'search' => ['get']
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
```

I am testing it with `postman` and passing `Authorization` in each api.

This is my header

[image]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear: the `HttpBearerAuth` class has no property `formats` so the following line shouldn't be under the `HttpBearerAuth` config:

```
'formats' => ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,],
```

This is a property of [\yii\filters\ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html). See the docs on [Content Negotiation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html#content-negotiation) for more details

Comment: I am passing `Content-Type : application/json` and `Accept : application/json` in header. Do I need to add something else. Doc is saying `$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json; q=1.0, */*; q=0.1" "http://localhost/users"`

Comment: I don't think you need to add anything else. Try it and see

Comment: when I removed that line I got `{"name":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid JSON data in request body: Syntax error.","code":0,"status":400,"type":"yii\\web\\BadRequestHttpException"}`

Comment: Is your request body json?

Comment: I am trying to send it with curl too. Here is the post field. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nkapik sharma\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",` And That is the header `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer 4p9mj82PTl1BWSya7bfpU_Nm8u07hkcB",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "postman-token: b0838a8c-9c3f-10bb-0556-5fc6c4f8ddc8"
  ),`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136461/discussion-between-topher-and-urfusion).